# How to calculate the differentiation of this expressions which contains matrix variable?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices

it is assumed that $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric, and
$\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{M}^\textsf{T}{\mathbf{X}}^{-1}\mathbf{M}$, where $\mathbf{M}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ has no special structure. Please calculate the differentiation $\frac{\partial(\ln|\det(\mathbf{Y})|)}{\partial\mathbf{X}}$.

My reference is "The Matrix Cookbook" written by Kaare Brandt Petersen, the link is http://matrixcookbook.com. But I still can not figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $V_n$ the vector space of symmetric $n\times n$ real matrices and by $U_n$ the (open) subset of $V_n$ consisting of invertible matrices. Now consider the following four functions:
$$
f_1:\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}, \quad x\mapsto \ln|x|,
$$
$$
f_2: V_m\to \mathbb{R}, \quad \mathbf{X}\mapsto \det(\mathbf{X}),
$$
$$
f_3: V_n\to V_m, \quad \mathbf{X}\mapsto \mathbf{M}^\top \mathbf{X}\mathbf{M}
$$
and
$$
f_4: U_n\to V_n, \quad \mathbf{X}\mapsto \mathbf{X}^{-1}.
$$
Then $\ln|\det(\mathbf{Y})|=(f_1\circ f_2\circ f_3\circ f_4)(\mathbf{X})$.

Now note that $f_1$ is differentiable, with derivative
$$
f_1'(x)(h) = \frac{h}{x}.
$$
The function $f_2$ is differentiable with derivative
$$
f_2'(\mathbf{X})(\mathbf{H}) = \mathrm{tr}((\mathrm{adj}(\mathbf{X}))\mathbf{H})
$$
as you can see in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/765772), where $\mathrm{tr}$ is the trace and $\mathrm{adj}(\mathbf{X})$ is the adjoint matrix of $\mathbf{X}$. Also, $f_3$ is a linear map, so it is differentiable and $f_3'(\mathbf{X})=f_3$. Finally $f_4$ is differentiable with derivative
$$
f_4'(\mathbf{X})(\mathbf{H}) = - \mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{H}\mathbf{X}^{-1}
$$
as you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/792941).

From this, you can obtain the desired derivative by using the chain rule.

**ADDED:** I'm going to show how to finish the computation using the chain rule. Write $f = f_1\circ f_2\circ f_3\circ f_4$. Let's do it step by step:
$$
(f_3\circ f_4)'(\mathbf{X})(\mathbf{H}) = (f_3'(f_4(\mathbf{X}))\circ f_4'(\mathbf{X}))(\mathbf{H}) = -\mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{H}\mathbf{X}^{-1}.
$$
Next
$$
(f_2\circ f_3\circ f_4)'(\mathbf{X})(\mathbf{H}) = f_2'(f_3\circ f_4(\mathbf{X}))\circ (f_3\circ f_4)'(\mathbf{X})(\mathbf{H})=\mathbf{M}^\top(-\mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{H}\mathbf{X}^{-1})\mathbf{M},
$$
and finally, in order to $f$ to be differentiable we need that $\mathbf{M}^\top \mathbf{X^{-1}}\mathbf{M}$ to be invertible, so we need to restrict $f$ to an open set where this occurs, and for such $\mathbf{X}$ we have
$$
f'(\mathbf{X})(\mathbf{H}) = f_1'((f_2\circ f_3\circ f_4)(\mathbf{X}))\circ (f_2\circ f_3\circ f_4)'(\mathbf{X})(\mathbf{H}) = -\frac{\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{adj}(\mathbf{M}^\top \mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{M})\mathbf{M}^\top \mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{H}\mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{M})}{\det(\mathbf{M}^\top \mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{M})} = -\frac{\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{M}\mathrm{adj}(\mathbf{M}^\top \mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{M})\mathbf{M}^\top \mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{H})}{\det(\mathbf{M}^\top \mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{M})}
$$
which means that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = -\frac{\mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{M}\mathrm{adj}(\mathbf{M}^\top \mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{M})\mathbf{M}^\top \mathbf{X}^{-1}}{\det(\mathbf{M}^\top \mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{M}} = -\mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{M}\mathbf{Y}^{-1}\mathbf{M}^\top \mathbf{X}^{-1},
$$
which is the desired derivative.

Comment: very clear! I think this answer is exactly what I want, but I still do not know how to use the chain rule...

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\X{X^{-1}}  \def\Y{Y^{-1}}
$First, calculate the differentials of $\,\X{\rm\;and\;}Y$
$$\eqalign{
&d\X = -\X dX\; \X \\
&dY = M^T\c{d\X}M \;=\; -{M^T\X dX\;\X M} \\
}$$
Then use a variant of [Jacobi's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula#Alternative_Derivation) to handle the determinant
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \log(\det(Y)) \\
d\phi &= \Y:dY \\
 &= -\Y:\LR{M^T\X dX\;\X M} \\
 &= -\LR{\X M\Y M^T\X}:dX \\
\grad{\phi}{X} &= -{\X M\Y M^T\X} \\
}$$
where a colon denotes the Frobenius product, which has the following properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \;=\; \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$
In the current problem, $\,X{\rm\;and\;}Y\,$ are symmetric, which simplifies some of the calculations.

$[$All relevant formulas can be found on page 9
of the [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)$ ]$